# Find 1st occurance of string pattern and extract a substring from it

Tags: sed

I need to search for 1st occurrence of string pattern "EPMAT-" in a log file and extract the numeric part from it. EPMAT- will be followed by some number. I would like to extract 20 from EPMAT-20 and print it.

Ex file:

```
This is a test  
test EPMAT-20 ......  
....  
EPMAT.33 test  
end of test.
```

Comment: Please decide whether you want `EPMAT` searched or `EMPAT`...

Comment: sorry my bad, it is EPMAT

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -m1 -oP '\bEPMAT-\K\d+' yourfile
```

`-m1` will just look at the first match in the whole of file

`-P` will enable the Perl regex engine.

`-o` will show only the matching portion

```
perl -lne 'print,exit for /\bEPMAT-\K\d+/g' yourfile

sed -ne '
   /\<EPMAT-[0-9][0-9]*/{
      s//&\
/
      s/.*-\([0-9]*\n\)/\1/
      P;q
   }
' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/EPMAT/{ s/.*EPMAT-//; s/[^0-9].*//; p; q; }' file
```